# Android GridView Issue

Tags: android, gridview, onclick

In `GridView` the item at index 1 is not receiving click event but all other items are receiving click event in Galaxy S and in HTC Hero all items are receiving click event.
What is this? 
Please explain.......thanks for giving time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldnt have any issues with this. i have used it tons of times. be sure to check the code you are using. Try to log the position in onItemClick see what it returns. also click don't work if you are using buttons or other similar controls inside the list rows. that requires a different aproach.